# Converting int to float in C function

Tags: c

So I have some source code that needs to be modified to include a 3rd mathematical formula.

The source code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_and_diff (int a, int b, int *res)
{
    int sum;
    sum = a + b;
    *res = a – b;
    return sum;
}
int main (void)
{
    int b = 2;
    int diff;
    printf ("The sum of 5 and %d is %d\n", b,
        sum_and_diff (5, b, &diff));
    printf ("The difference of 5 and %d is %d\n", b, diff);
}
```

It needs to be modified by adding a division function and all arguments that pass through it should be converted to float.

This is what I have done so far, and for the life of me it will not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int sum_and_diff (int a, int b, int *res)
{
    int sum;
    sum = a + b;
    *res = a – b;
    return sum;
}
    
float div (float a, float b)
{
    float div;
    div = a / b;
    return div;
}
    
void main (void)
{
    float a = 5.0;
    int b = 2;
    int diff;
    float div;
    
    printf ("The sum of 5 and %d is %d\n", b,
        sum_and_diff (5, b, &diff));
    printf ("The difference of 5 and %d is %d\n", b,  diff);
    printf ("The quotient of %.0f and %d is %f\n", a, b, div);
}
```

Can someone please help me correct this, I have been at this for hours and just about every resource online says that you can't convert int to float in C.

Instead it compiles fine, but the 3rd print gives me a result of -nan.

Comment: The `div` function is never called.

Comment: Try _calling_ `div()` with `printf ("quotient: %g\n",  div(a,b));`

Comment: Corrected that, sorry I was busy editing at the time you posed.  The error message I am getting is "div is used uninitialized in this function"

Comment: You also have a very peculiar arrangement of curly braces, and there is a weird non-ASCII character somewhere in your `*res = a – b;` line.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. See https://onlinegdb.com/whysWrTAx. Please correct it.

Comment: @Adrian sorry about that, VirtualBox is being finicky about copy/paste right now.  Transcription by hand is never a good option for this kind of work lol.

Comment: Remove the `float div;` declaration from `main` and call your `div` function as the argument to `printf`.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I fixed it, sorry bout the mistake there, I was transcribing by hand because VirtualBox is being insolent right now.  https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/whysWrTAx

Comment: Still no good. https://onlinegdb.com/eWOdVwxyv

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica It's solved.  Someone was able to help me structure it within the print statement and that got it working.  https://www.onlinegdb.com/cw12CCTUH  Thank you again for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
float div;
// ...
printf ("The quotient of %.0f and %d is %f\n", a, b, div);
```

You declared a local variable called `div` which has no connection to the function named `div` (but [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) it).  Then you print out the value of this variable, which was never initialized and therefore contains garbage, resulting in incorrect output or other undefined behavior.

You should delete the declaration `float div;` and instead call the function:

```
printf ("The quotient of %.0f and %d is %f\n", a, b, div(a,b));
```

Try it: https://onlinegdb.com/cw12CCTUH

Comment: You are a godsend!  Thank you so much.